# Websites to practice SQA

Tags: manual-testing

I just started learning SQA and before taking on paid projects I'd like to practice myself. Are there any websites where I can practice my testing skills? I have some programming skills and if I would try to perform a test on my own website I know that I won't find any mistakes because the websites are pretty simple. So, are there any websites at all that I can practice on?

Comment: A simple web search will get you a lot of results. Plus you can get open source project from sourceforge, github and other such repositories.

Comment: Automated or manual testing?

Comment: @FDM I assume automated testing, because Eva mentions she has (some) programming skills.

Answer (score 5):

You may get your first **Manual testing** practice project on this link

> http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/free-online-software-testing-qa-training-course/

here in this project, you will get a better idea about STLC (Software Testing Life Cycle) or Testing process, the best thing about this project you can practice STLC. In this project, you will find step wise step process with respect of days, read it and practice it as per instruction.

Then you can practice on some demo sites, like

> http://phptravels.com/demo/
>
> http://thedemosite.co.uk/
>
> http://newtours.demoaut.com/
>
> http://www.way2automation.com/demo.html
>
> http://automationpractice.com/index.php
>
> http://demoqa.com/

After completing this you can perform testing on any website or application  as **nothing is perfect or bug-free,** In starting it may be difficult to find bug **but not impossible.**

Answer (score 2):

Automated testing of a website is just automating a browser to do whatever you want to do with a page.

So first step is to become a competent programmer: know your language, know how to design data structures, design patterns.

Read about design patterns you need to write competent programs. One design pattern you definitely want to use in QA is PageObject.

Get any website, try automating browser with any interaction you would want to do with it. The only restriction would be, do not hit the website too much, so you don't consume too many resources.

Doing whatever you want to do with a website is the hard part. Checking that website responded correctly is the easy part.

Answer (score 2):

My first site to practice on was [gruyere](https://google-gruyere.appspot.com/) from Google. I know some people use this for security testing but I found it useful to have the dev tools on a browser open and explore what was happening on the application.

The [Presta](http://demo.prestashop.com/en/?view=front) shop was also recommended to me when I asked [a similar question](https://club.ministryoftesting.com/t/products-and-sites-to-practice-testing-on/1242).

When I took a course with the Software Testing Clinic recently, we tested Bing. The iOS app vs the android app vs it on different browsers. We found quite a few inconsistencies. This led me then to have a look at other sites/apps I'd never used before to see what I could find.

Answer (score 1):

Ready for test buggy applications

```
https://asta.pgs-soft.com
Automated Software Testing Arena, also good for manual testing

http://mrbuggy.eu
MrBuggy set of great buggy apps to test on
```

Apps that you can test locally.

```
https://instantwp.com
Fast wordpress setup

https://github.com/tourdedave/the-internet
Herokuapp. The internet. GitHub project
```

Interactive projects that are free

```
http://www.guru99.com/live-testing-project.html
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/free-online-software-testing-qa-training-course/
```

For automation purpose:

```
Herokuapp. The internet.
http://the-internet.herokuapp.com

https://asta.pgs-soft.com
Automated Software Testing Arena

http://timvroom.com/selenium/playground/
Playground with various tasks

http://automationpractice.com
Virtual e-shop

http://demoqa.com
Various content

http://newtours.demoaut.com
Tourism webpage

http://bdonline.sqe.com
B&D is a fictitious online brokerage firm

http://adam.goucher.ca/parkcalc
This "application" has some serious flaws, and has been the subject of lots of exploratory testing.

http://executeautomation.com/demosite/index.html
User forms

http://Enterprise.Demo.Orangehrmlive.Com/
Demo HR management site

http://www.way2automation.com/demo.html
Various elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your most frequently visited websites and apply your exploratory testing skills to these sites - you would be surprised as to how you see it differently as a tester compared to when you would casually viewing as a consumer. Give yourself a timebox and explore as much of the website as you can. Spot a bug? File it! Most webmasters/teams would be stoked that you care enough to report an issue. In any case, it will help you practice filing bug reports.

If you don't feel challenged enough exploring your own website due to its simplicity, perhaps try approaching it through a different lens. There are many different ways you can go about testing a website no matter how simple - have you exhausted all possible test scenarios and combinations? Have you tried switching up your overall methodology?

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for BugFinders or uTest. They have training materials and practice projects/testing sandboxes that you can take advantage of, and once you're ready for it you can apply what you learned on a paid project. There are a number of crowdsourced testing sites, but those are the two that I used to get some additional testing experience before starting my current QA job.